# Run function when cicking off a div thats Contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a table that has a couble od tds, the tds contain divs that allows the user to change the value within it. If the user presses enter a function is called but I would now like to make it so the user only has to click away from the div for the function to run. is this possible?

Comment: You are looking for a `blur` or `focusout` event handler. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

Comment: blur solved the problem i had thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) event:

```js
$('.edit-me').prop('contentEditable', true);
$('.edit-me').on('blur', function() { console.log( $(this).text() ); });
```

```css
table    { width: 100%;   }
table td { width: 50%;    }
.edit-me { padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="edit-me"></div></td>
    <td><div class="edit-me"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="edit-me"></div></td>
    <td><div class="edit-me"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to be able to select an element based on whether or not it has the contenteditable attribute:

```
$('[contenteditable="true"]')
```

Then apply event to it

Comment: The OP hasn't suggested that they're struggling with selecting the element. Also, *then apply event to it* isn't useful. What event?!

Comment: If the user presses enter a function is called but I would now like to make it so the user only has to click away from the div for the function to run. The event is blur the selection is according to the contenteditable attribute